# Lockheed SR-71 take off protocol

Tags: military, takeoff, engine

I'm intrigued by the Lockheed SR-71's take-off procedure, as it seems different to that of civilian aircraft. I would like to know what are the major differences in take-off procedure, and why?

For example, most aircraft begin to take off like the following: *engine one on, warming up. Engine two on, warming up, etc.* But is this the same for the SR-71 what was its take-off protocol?

Comment: Are you asking about takeoff? Your example sounds like just engine start.

Comment: No as in, did they warm it up did they take off immediately, did they have to check weight, did they have to do the calculations of (weight fuel and cargo).

Comment: Can you, if possible, provide a link to or more in depth description of the procedures in question. This question is a bit vague but I feel it can be honed into a solid question.

Comment: I recommend this book, it really goes into more detail than anything else: *Flying the SR-71 Blackbird: In the Cockpit on a Secret Operational Mission*  http://www.amazon.com/Flying-SR-71-Blackbird-Cockpit-Operational/dp/0760332398

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are referencing the [manuals found here](http://www.sr-71.org/blackbird/manual/2/) the procedures look pretty standard to me. Granted they involve some thing specific to the plane they are generally what one would find. Pages [2-19](http://www.sr-71.org/blackbird/manual/2/2-19.php) through [2-23](http://www.sr-71.org/blackbird/manual/2/2-23.php) seems to cover the start up procedure and it looks pretty standard. Make sure ground unit is connected, check fuel flow, check engine is open, start, check RMP (provides some trouble shooting for RPM issues as well). It also goes on to say left engine first for odd flights and right engine first for even flights to keep the wear some what in line. There are a lot of "Note" sections but you are talking about one of if not the highest performance aircraft ever made so these are to be expected.